# SharePoint 2010 - Search Web Parts - Modify XSL

Tags: search, branding

Ok … I am getting a little out of my depth here and need some help. I am pretty new to branding but make some really good strides, have our own master pages, page layouts and everything is working good. But ...

I need to tweak what the search results look like along with messaging for no results found. The web parts I am using are:

- Search Summary
- Search Core Results
- Search Paging

The ‘Search Summary’ webpart has no options so I have no idea how to edit it.

The ‘Search Paging’ works fine, I will see about overriding the styles and should be fine.

It is the ‘Core Search Results’ that I have to get into. When I have the ‘Use Selection Visualization’ unchecked it seems that I can open the XSL Editor. The question is where is that XSL and what is the workflow around it? Like is it encapsulated in the instance of that web part or am I changing something globally?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

It is encapsulated in the instance of the web part on the page you added it to. Changing the XSL will only effect that web part on that page.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Hello,

Indeed the web part XSL you modify is only for the current page where web part is inserted.

To be able not to change this XSL all the time I can advise you to:

1. Insert OOTB serach web part on the page
2. Chenge its XSL to desired one (custom)
3. Export web  part using drop down menu of the web part (same as to call properties)
4. Get this XML definition and craete your own web part file as element
5. Install this web part using feature.

This way will give you semi-custom web part which will be the same. All you will need to do is to insert this web part on the each page where needed.

To install web part with element.xml use this code:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="ListingWebParts" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="your_web_part_file_path_in_the_solution/your_web_part_file"  Url="your_web_part_file" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="Web_Part_Title"></Property>
      <Property Name="Group" Value="You_Group" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Hope it helps,

Andrew